# StackExchange is lower case on gaming

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

The <kbd>S</kbd> in the StackExchange dropdown on Gaming is lowercased. Is this intentional?

[image]

vs

[image]

Comment: Yes I see it hm

Comment: I mentioned this to [Jin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) in chat earlier, so hopefully it's already on the to-do list.

Comment: In your post, the space in its name is missing!

Comment: @Arjan: I don't think it should have a space. It doesn't have a space in either image. Stack Overflow also doesn't have a space in it's logo.

Comment: @Dexter, surely there's a difference in *writing* a name (like you did) and using a logo (which is what is above the dropdown). As an aside: the logo is partly bold to indicate there are two words.

Comment: @Arjan: What about FedEx? I think it's important to be consistent. You shouldn't have one way for writing and another for logos.

Comment: One thing [is sure](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance): the names need a space. (Sure, your question is an edge case, given it's about the logo, though that is only clear given the screenshots.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was not intentional, thanks for catching this. I have updated the sprites for gaming and gaming meta. Will be in the next deployment.